# How do I execute a string as code in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a string stored in a database that I'm pulling into an array lets say for example the string is "$foo" what I'm trying to do is use that string as a  php variable to be interpreted by php, but I can't seem to figure it out. I did try using eval, but I couldn't get that to work in my current code and from what I've read eval() is too dangerous to use in a live environment.

Here is a sample of my code

```
$result = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM newordersystem");
for ($set = array (); $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); $set[] = $row);
foreach ($set as $item) {

$item[PHPVARIABLE] = stripslashes($_POST[$item[INPUTIDNAME]]);}
```

The last line is where my problem lies, in that I want "$item[PHPVARIABLE]" to execute as $foo so the result would end up being $foo = 1

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `eval()` is the answer. It is a bad idea. What result did you get when you used it?

Comment: Sounds like a case for variable variables: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: I was wrapping, the eval around only the first part before the =, would I wrap the eval() around that entire line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange architecture and I don't get 100% your goal, but if you need:

`$item[$item[INPUTIDNAME]] = stripslashes($_POST[$item[INPUTIDNAME]]);}`

or

`${$item[PHPVARIABLE]} = stripslashes($_POST[$item[INPUTIDNAME]]);}`